# How to return a custom view OR a JSON when the Authorization fail, instead of showing a username and password dialog

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, authorize-attribute

I am working on an asp.net mvc 4 web application , and i wrote the following custom authorization class:-

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]

    public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                return false;
            //code goes here
            if (!repository.can(ADusername, Model, value)) // implement this method based on your tables and logic
            {

                return false;
                //base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
            return true;

           // base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                var viewResult = new JsonResult();
                viewResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
                viewResult.Data = (new { IsSuccess = "Unauthorized", description = "Sorry, you do not have the required permission to perform this action." });
                filterContext.Result = viewResult;

            }
            else
            {
                var viewResult = new ViewResult();

                viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml";

                filterContext.Result = viewResult;
            }

            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

but the only problem i am facing now is that if the authorization fail then the user will be prompted to enter username and password, although i have override the HandleUnauthorizedRequest to return a view or JSON based on if the request is AJAX or not. so can you advice why the user is being prompted to enter his username and password when the authorization fail, instead of receiving the _unauthorized view or the JSON containing an error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but the only problem i am facing now is that if the authorization fail
>   then the user will be prompted to enter username and password,
>   although i have override the HandleUnauthorizedRequest to return a
>   view or JSON based on if the request is AJAX or not.

That's because you are absolutely always hitting the following line in your `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method:

```
base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
```

You know what this line do? It calls the base method. You know what the base method do? It returns 401 status code. You know what happens when 401 status response code is returned in an ASP.NET application in which you are using Forms Authentication? You get the login page.

So yeah, if you are using AJAX or something and intend to be returning some JSON or something make sure that the base stuff is never called. By the way in your `else` condition you seem to be attempting to render some `~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml` view which obviously is useless once again because you are also calling the base method which will simply redirect to the login page.

I think that at this stage of my answer you already know what to do: get rid of this last line of your `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method in which you are throwing all your efforts into the trash by calling the base method.

And if you want to do things properly and return 401 status code and not get the login page but instead return some custom JSON you could use the [`SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.suppressformsauthenticationredirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on the Response object. And if you are using some legacy version of the .NET framework which doesn't have this property you might find the [`following blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx/) useful in which Phil Haack explains how to handle this case.

Comment: yes i removed the base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext); and things is working well now. but can you advice why it is better to return 401 instead of true or false?? .. by the way i am not using form authentication , instead my application use windows authentication.

Comment: *Why it is better to return 401 instead of true or false*? Because the HTTP protocol dictates that if a user is not authorized to access some resource the server should return 401 status code. So why reinvent the wheels with true or false stuff when the HTTP protocol already has everything needed to handle this case?

Comment: but since on my ajax calls (ajax.actionlink & ajax.beginform) i am expecting the JSON on the OnSuccess scripts to display unauthorized message, so if i return 401 then i need to call onfailure script instead. so currently things is working well , and i am thinking to keep it the way it is ? can you advice if this might cause other problems?

Comment: No, it might not cause other problems. It's just that the correct way to handle a 401 status code is to subscribe to the onerror callback. And as I said in my previous comment the correct thing to do when a user is not authorized to access some resource is to return 401 status code. But you could of course violate the HTTP protocol and handle your errors in the `success` callback of your AJAX requests :-)

Comment: but in this case how i will be returning both JSON and 401 at the same time. is this possible to return two values from my HandleUnauthorizedRequest method ??